# How to fill a rectangle with color when there is a shader in Processing?

Tags: opengl, processing

Usually with Processing, you fill a rectangle with a given color like so:

```
fill(255, 0, 0); // Make it red
rect(0,0, 100, 100); // Make it square
```

However, this does not work. Instead, the rectangle displays [this shader](https://github.com/genekogan/Processing-Shader-Examples/blob/master/ColorShaders/data/nebula.glsl). Somewhere earlier in the execution I call this:

```
PShader shader = loadShader(filePath); // A shader is loaded once upon startup
// In a draw() method
shader(shader);
rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

This draws a rectangle which covers the whole screen, and a nice dynamic background is displayed.

Why does the fill() call have no effect and why is the shader drawn in the rectangle instead? How can I keep the background shader and also display a red rectangle in Processing?

Comment: never say "this does not work" when it certainly does. It might not work in the code you're using, but then you need to show all the code you're using (reduced so that code that does not contribute to the problem is left out) so that others can run the same code and reproduce your problem. You have not given us enough code to do that in your question yet.

Comment: This IS the reduced relevant code. It is clear that I expect a red rectangle and I have desribed what I get instead.

Comment: as a Processing sketch, where's the `setup()` function with your `size()` call? Where's the `draw()` function to trigger the drawing? etc.

Comment: Honestly, setup(), which sets the resolution, is not relevant to the question at hand. The sketch is a game with 26 .pde files and as such it simply would not be productive to go into detail about the history of the draw function. The issue is simple, and reproducible with minimal code. The Nebula example sketch (under shaders) can be modified to try to draw a rectangle on top of the shader.

Comment: it kind of is, because without `setup` you can't call custom functions. And `size()` is **incredibly** important if you read [the documentation](https://processing.org/reference/shader_.html) for how to use the `shader()` function: if you don't have a size call, then you can't start the sketch in a shader-compatible mode. As for your "real" program, it doesn't really matter how big that is, since you only write a [minimum working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a SO post (as a Processing program, that's a setup() + draw() definition with the failing code that we can copy-paste)